# NSDate setting the time, not the expected result

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have the following code to set the time on a date to 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds by using the YEAR, MONTH and DAY components from the date to construct a new one:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
NSLog(@"date: %@, newDate: %@", date, newDate);
```

The output is:

```
date: 2012-11-06 11:44:09 +0000, newDate: 2012-11-05 23:00:00 +0000
```

but I was expecting the new date to be: `2012-11-06 00:00:00 +0000`
What's happening that I should know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSLog` shows the dates using `-[NSDate description]` which, in turn, converts the absolute time stored in the `NSDate` to a string. This conversion is done using UTC as the time zone.

For you case it's probably best to do the date calculations in UTC as well. To do so adjust the calendar object that does the calculations:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689829/696624) for a similar Stack Overflow question.

This should solve your issue with daylight savings:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Printing the date using the above formatter settings is the same. Could you provide some clarification on how daylight savings affect NSDate creation or the calendar?

Comment: Daylight savings affect the results of `[NSDate date]` by taking into consideration the time zone of the device/user settings. By using different time zones, it is possible to determine a date in relation to another time zone. See the edit made to my answer.

Comment: @CaptainRedmuff "Daylight savings affect the results of [NSDate date]": That's not true; `NSDate` is not affected by calendars, timezones, locales, etc. `NSDate` represents an absolute point in time.